# Rename file using batch script appending last week monday to set date

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I am trying to rename `abc.xlsx` to `abc-02_16_20 - 02_22_20.xlsx`

I am not able to make the second part of the date.

Can any one help on this.

I have tried this:

```
@echo on

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

copy "C:\Users\****\Desktop\aaa.xlsx" "C:\Users\***\Desktop\aaa - %stamp%.xlsx"

pause
```

Comment: The best way to rename your file is to use the `ren`/`rename` command, not the `copy` command! You also need to explain what you mean by, "i am not able to make the second part of the date ." If the problem is that the destination is for a different user, _(one is `****`, and the other is `***`)_, then you'd need to have sufficient privileges to copy from and write to each users locations.

Comment: What os? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @somebadhat - I'm having a hard time envisioning a solution where that matters

Comment: Your rename example doesn't match the format of the timestamp variable.

Comment: What the problem appears to be is that the OP isn't wanting to rename using today's date, the title tells us they're wanting to use the date of the last Monday of the previous week. The reason it's not working is therefore that they have not in any way attempted to determine that date. The question is therefore off topic as their code isn't exhibiting an issue. They just want us to provide the code to bolt onto theirs.